# Merging Contacts in List view

Tags: java, android, contacts

What i would like to do is following: I have a custom list view which displays all the device contacts along with duplicates names.

Now I would like to merge the contacts with same names. I can have different numbers with same name. All this should come under single name.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your code?

Comment: i just implement the basic display of contacts in the listview and i'm struck here

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap<String,List<String>> ContactList;
```

The first string in the [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is a Key - means duplicate will be automtically earsed.
The second [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is expandable collection and also the value of the hash map - means you can have List of strings that can be duplicated across the HashMap.